# Dynamically prevent onKeyUp function

Tags: jquery, ajax, onkeyup

I am trying to build in a Facebook like link share preview. For those visually inclined, something like this:

[image]

Everything is working fine but for a couple of small things. The link share preview is triggered upon a **keyup function in the corresponding textarea**. Something like this:

```
$('#txtPublish').keyup(function(e){
                if ($(this).val() != '' && $(this).parent().find('.share-with').hasClass('active')) {   

                     detectHyperlink(e,this);
                  }
                  else {
            //do whatever
                  }
            });
```

And the corresponding detectHyperlink begins like this:

```
function detectHyperlink(e,textarea)
{
    if((e.which == 13 || e.which == 32 || e.which == 17) && ($(textarea).val().trim() != "")){
        var hyperlink_post = $('#txtPublish').val(); // make dynamic
        if(hyperlink_post != null) {
            hyperlink_post = " " + hyperlink_post;
            var urlRegex = /(https?\:\/\/|\s)[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})(\/+[a-z0-9_.\:\;-]*)*(\?[\&\%\|\+a-z0-9_=,\.\:\;-]*)?([\&\%\|\+&a-z0-9_=,\:\;\.-]*)([\!\#\/\&\%\|\+a-z0-9_=,\:\;\.-]*)}*/i;
            if(urlRegex.test(hyperlink_post)){
                        // SImple DOM Manipulation


            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '/controller/crawlHyperlink',
                data: {message: hyperlink_post},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
```

// data is in JSON offcourse for those interested in these things.

This works fine, but the problem is this: The detectHyperlink method keeps getting called just more than once. That is, once the Textarea has detected a hyper link and shared the information, it still keeps looping and making ajax calls to the server. So when I hit the Post button, it still makes a couple of calls to the server to detect the hyperlink before it actually posts this information back.

Can you guys spot why ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$('#txtPublish').one('keyup', function(){ ...`

Comment: so one will technically execute only once right. So on the first every instance of keyup it executes but does not execute after that?  correct ?

Comment: Yes. The `.one(` will only execute once.

Comment: so how will that help my cause. The keyup function as you know is waiting for the right regex pattern to appear so that it is able to find out a hyperlink.

Comment: My apologies, I must have misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to supress the default hyperlink action if you are overriding it with jQuery.

```
$('#txtPublish').keyup(function(e){
  if ($(this).val() != '' && $(this).parent().find('.share-with').hasClass('active')) {   
    detectHyperlink(e,this);
    e.preventDefault();//prevents default submit() from firing
    }
```

In addition you may want to set a temporary flag when the ajax is called, and prevent it from executing again if the flag is set.

```
if (ajaxWasCalled==false) {
  $.ajax({
    ...
    ajaxWasCalled=true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: in your comments it states that i prevents <a href ... > from firing. I am not sure I understand this, where is it being fired off at all ?

Comment: @parijat <a href="..."> links are normally going to try to navigate to the URI they are set to when clicked. e.preventDefault is a jQuery override that suppresses this behavior. See: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: ummm...no one is clicking on these links in the txtPublish. These are textareas, and the user is scribbling down a hyperlink, which the javascript is detecting by regex pattern matching.

Comment: @parijat sorry I just noticed its not the link thats firing, its the page submit. It will still prevent the dupe behavior.

Comment: i am still confused by your answer. Do you mean default behavior by dupe behavior? If so, I do understand default behavior can be prevented but not sure why you are asking me to prevent it. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @parijat The ajax routine appears to be called anytime ASCII values 13 , 32 or 17 are typed in the textarea, and meets additional criteria. Again, I was wrong, I thought the user was clicking on a text link initially (so e.preventDefault may not be needed). Is there a reason you are validating the entered hyperlink while they are entering it, rather than after they have clicked "POST"?

Comment: yes. You haven't read the question carefully. This is a hyperlink preview function. You are trying to give the user a preview of the hyperlink before he actually posts that information to the server so naturally it has to be done before you POST not after

Comment: @parijat Aha. I misunderstood because you wrote "So when I hit the Post button, it still makes a couple of calls to the server to detect the hyperlink before it actually posts this information back." Maybe try $('#txtPublish').change instead of $.keyup?

Comment: sorry about the confusion. yes, technically it makes multiple ajax requests to the server....thanks